# UI Layout issue

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am struggling with layout format in flutter. My problem is that after the CarouselSlider there is a greater space than I require. What is the best way to structure a layout to avoid future issues.

Thank you

And I realise my post is mainly code so have to write this section, is there a way to avoid this as I want to post my full code for clarity

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  HomeScreen({Key key, @required this.name}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final List<String> hotelCategories = StubData().hotelCategories;
  int checkedItem = 0;
  var _current = 0;
  List<T> map<T>(List list, Function handler) {
    List<T> result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      result.add(handler(i, list[i]));
    }

    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(70, 109, 69, 1.0),
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      drawer:  SideDrawer(user:widget.name),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0,0,10.0,0),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
            Text("Sponsored ",
            style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                     color: Colors.black,
                    ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.4,
               autoPlay: true,//
              viewportFraction: 1.0,
              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                setState(() {
                  _current = index;
                  });
              }
              ),
              items: map<Widget>(
                foods,
                    (index, i){
                      Map food = foods[index];
                  return SliderItem(
                    img: food['img'],
                    name: food['name'],
                    desc: food['desc'],
                    rate: food['rate'],
                  );
                },
              ).toList(),
              ),
                            Container(
                height: 32,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          checkedItem = index;
                        });
                      },
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        height: double.infinity,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: index == 0 ? 20 : 5, right: 5),

                        child: Center(
                          child:
                          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              hotelCategories[index],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  //color: index == checkedItem
                                      //? Colors.white
                                     // : themeData.accentColor),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ));
                  },

                ))],
              ),
              ),

    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this make your items of CarouselSlider smaller you make it a child of a sizedBox or you can make it child of a Flexible widget and use a column instead of listview i hope this solves your problem

Comment: Hmmmm I need the page to scroll? I am totally new to flutter and the layout blows my mind. thanks. Can you provide a sample please

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(70, 109, 69, 1.0),
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      drawer:  SideDrawer(user:widget.name),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0,0,10.0,0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
            Text("Sponsored ",
            style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                     color: Colors.black,
                    ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Expanded(child:
            CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
               autoPlay: true,//
              viewportFraction: 1.0,
              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                setState(() {
                  _current = index;
                  });
              }
              ),
              items: map<Widget>(
                foods,
                    (index, i){
                      Map food = foods[index];
                  return SliderItem(
                    img: food['img'],
                    name: food['name'],
                    desc: food['desc'],
                    rate: food['rate'],
                  );
                },
              ).toList(),
              )),
                            Container(
                height: 32,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          checkedItem = index;
                        });
                      },
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        height: double.infinity,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: index == 0 ? 20 : 5, right: 5),

                        child: Center(
                          child:
                          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              hotelCategories[index],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  //color: index == checkedItem
                                      //? Colors.white
                                     // : themeData.accentColor),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ));
                  },

                ))],
              ),
              ),

    ),
    );
  }
```